# Simple Average Pooling with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pooling

I'm trying to do some very simple average pooling on a Keras / Tensorflow Tensor (not a layer in a network). I have a list of 18 embeddings (embedding = 2D vector) and want to average pool them with a pool-size of 3 with no overlap. So the first 3 embeddings should be averaged to an embedding, then the next 3 and so on. In the end, I need a list of 18/3 = 6 embeddings.

Here's my code so far:

```
    sequence_len = 3 # The number of embeddings that should be averaged
    feature_dim = 2 # the dimensions of embeddings
    input = [
        [1, 3],  # Anchor 1
        [2, 2],
        [3, 1],
        [4, 1],  # Anchor 2
        [6, 1],
        [8, 1],
        [12, 3],  # Positive 1
        [0, 6],
        [0, 0],
        [1, 1],  # Positive 2
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [5, 0],  # Negative 1
        [5, 12],
        [5, 0],
        [1, 1],  # Negative 2
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
    ]
    expected_out = [
        [2, 2],  # Anchor 1
        [6, 1],  # Anchor 2
        [4, 3],  # Positive 1
        [1, 1],  # Positive 2
        [5, 4],  # Negative 1
        [1, 1],  # Negative 2
    ]
    input_tensor = K.variable(input)
    output_tensor = a_function_i_cant_figure_out(input_tensor) # What's the API to call?
    assert numpy.array_equal(K.eval(output_tensor), expected_out)
```

I've spent over 2 hours on it now and I can't figure it out. I don't understand how I would have to reshape my data to get it to work with the [pooling function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/pool).

The closes I've come to a working solution is wrapping my input in another 2 lists (making it shape `(1,1,18,2)`) and calling this

```
output_tensor = K.pool2d(foo, (3, 2), (3, 2), pool_mode="avg", data_format="channels_first")
```

But this also averages the embeddings themselves. So instead of `[[2,2], [6,1], ...]` I'd receive `[2, 3.5, ...]`

This seems like such a trivial operation - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out:

```
output_tensor = K.tf.nn.pool(input_tensor, [1, sequence_len], strides=(1, sequence_len), pooling_type="AVG", padding="VALID")
```

Think of my data as a 2D matrix.

`[1, sequence_len]` is the pool/window size. So in X direction, we have a width of 1 and in Y direction a height of `sequence_len`. This means: The first value of `sequence_len` rows will be combined to one value. Then the stride of `(1, sequence_len)` means: We move the pool by 1 in X direction and once we're done with the row we move the pool down by `sequence_len`.

We go with a width of 1 and a X-step of 1 column by column through the data which means our output has the same width. In Y direction we pool `sequence_len` rows to 1 row and then take the next `sequence_len` rows with no overlap. So the height of our output is `original_height / sequence_len`

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.